# Pro Mini not communicating with computer

Tags: uploading

when I try to upload blink program to my Pro Mini, I get this error:

```
avrdude stk500_getsync() not in sync resp=0x00
```

I've tried everything, changing the COM port, different USB cable and even another computer. Here is what I'm dealing with:

Arduino Pro Mini 328 5v 16M (Fake)

FT232RL USB to serial adapter

Nothing is connected to any pins on the Arduino, just trying to get LED to blink. I'm pretty sure the bootloader is installed, because when I hit the reset button, the LED blinks. I've tested the FTDI chip by connecting the TX and RX pins together, and it does echo in the serial monitor.
Help appreciated!

Comment: Did you install the driver? What OS are you on?

Comment: Yes, the driver has been installed. I'm currently running Windows 7, although I have an IMac if needed.

Comment: Just curious, what happens when you use your iMac? I'm trying to figure out if it's your computer or Arduino.

Comment: I will try tomorrow and get back to you soon.

Comment: I've tried with my iMac and I get this error
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Comment: You'll get a similar message if there is no bootloader on the atmega328. Maybe the fake pro-mini is just blank. You can flash the bootloader using a working [arduino as ISP](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP).

Comment: I don't have another Arduino. I an also pretty sure there is a bootloader because when I press the reset button, The LED comes on for about a second, and then turns off. It will also occasionally blink.

Answer (score 1):

You did set the Serial Port and then tell the Arduino IDE that it's talking to a Pro Mini right?

This gets me every time I switch between my Nano & Uno.

On the main menu
[Tools]->[Board]=>"Arduino Pro or Pro Mini (5V, 16 MHz) w/ ATmega 328"

I've also had this problem trying to use a longer USB cable, it just wouldn't work.  The stock cable (shorter) worked fine.